# show Powershell variables and foreach output in email

Tags: powershell

I am trying to monitor specific folders of specific users mailboxes. My thought was to call the users using a variable and then run a foreach loop and send the output to an email so that it will be emailed to me.

Here is what I am starting with:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://ExchangeServer/PowerShell -Authentication Kerberos 
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber

$Users = 'user1','User2','user3','user4'

foreach($user in $users) {

    $message += "------------- <br>"
    $message +="checking user.... $user <br>"
    $message += "------------- <br>"

    $messsage += $report = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user | ?{$_.name -eq 'Top of Information Store' -or $_.name -eq 'Recoverable Items' -or $_.name -eq 'Deletions' -or $_.name -eq 'Purges' -or $_.name -eq 'Versions'}  | ft Name, ItemsInFolder, FolderAndSubFolderSize
   
}

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtpserver.domain.com -From Sender@domain.com -To MyEmailAddress@domain.com -Subject "Litigation Mailbox Size Report" -Body $message -BodyAsHtml

Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

I can get it to send me an email but all it has is the email is dashed lines with the users but not the results from the get-mailboxfolderstatistics. I have tried using the $report variable for the get-mailboxfolderstatistics and then not using it.  Neither seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, perhaps surprisingly, that won't make a difference, because chaining assignments is supported.

Comment: :) Excellent point, @SantiagoSquarzon, but that's not the only problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *immediate* explanation for your symptom is a *typo*: `$messsage` should be `$message`, as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out.

- To avoid such problems in scripts, consider setting [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) `-Version 1`, which prevents references to *nonexistent variables*. Higher versions implement additional checks (which can be problematic - see [GitHub issue #2798](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798)).

Even with the typo corrected, additional work is required:

You must use [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) in order to embed a *string rendering* of the *formatting instructions* that `Format-*` cmdlets such as [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) (aliased to `ft`) output:

```
$message += '<pre>{0}</pre>' -f (
  Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user |
    Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'Top of Information Store' -or $_.name -eq 'Recoverable Items' -or $_.name -eq 'Deletions' -or $_.name -eq 'Purges' -or $_.name -eq 'Versions' } |
      Format-Table Name, ItemsInFolder, FolderAndSubFolderSize |
        Out-String
)
```

The above additionally wraps the output in a `<pre>` HTML element, so that the content renders with a monospaced font for proper column alignment.

Note: `Out-String` unexpectedly appends a *trailing newline* - see [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444). Add `.TrimEnd()` to the `(...)` expression to remove it, or `.Trim()` to also remove leading whitespace (empty lines).

Comment: Doh! yes I did have a typo. My noob-ness shining through. Thank you both for your help . Mklement0 using your out-file code did resolve the issue. I will also look to use set-strictmode in feature scripts. Great explanation appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @TDx2; my pleasure.